# Exception throw for null data with optional Int type in Realm

Tags: swift, realm

I am taking my first foray into using Realm (0.98.1 via Cocoapods, Xcode 7.2) and am running into a small problem that I am not sure how to solve.

I have a model class called Airport that declares a property

`let elevationFt = RealmOptional<Int>()`

I am creating a set of Airport objects and persisting them in the following way

```
public func cacheDataToPersistanceStore(data:NSArray) -> Bool {
    var success = true
    autoreleasepool {
        do {
            let realm = try Realm()
            realm.beginWrite()
            for object in data {
                guard let dictionaryValues = object as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> else {
                    debugPrint("Unable to convert data to correct type")
                    success = false
                    return
                }
                if(dictionaryValues["airportID"] as! Int == 6605) {
                    realm.create(Airport.self, value: dictionaryValues, update: true)
                }

            }

            try realm.commitWrite()
        }
        catch(let e) {
            debugPrint(e)
            success = false
        }
    }

    return success

}
```

For the airport entry in question, the dictionary that stores the relevant data looks to have a null value for the key "elevationFt", so I assume things will be OK for the optional Int property

[image: Image of debug view for dictionary]

Here is a string version of the dictionary:

["gps_code": 01MD, "ident": 01MD, "iata_code": , "local_code": 01MD, "keywords": , "elevationFt": , "type": seaplane_base, "municipality": Annapolis, "iso_country": US, "airportID": 6605, "longitudeDeg": -76.45600128173828, "latitudeDeg": 38.99919891357422, "iso_region": US-MD, "wikipedia_link": , "name": Annapolis Seaplane Base, "scheduled_service": no, "continent": NA, "home_link": ]

However once the create function starts for this set of data, an exception is thrown:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Invalid value '' for property 'elevationFt''
```

I am guessing I have something set up incorrectly, but I am not quite sure how to fix this other than to clean my source data for that particular field.

Comment: Seems like there is something fishy in your `dictionaryValues` object.

Comment: May very well be. The source data is a CSV that was converted to JSON strings and then back to JSONObjects via NSJSONSerialization. A bit round the houses, but seemed to be needed as otherwise the data types were completely lost and everything was a string. The dictionary when printed looks good and I have added to the data above.

Comment: Could you print out the class of elevationFt from the dictionary? It seems like it's converted to something else than it should be.

Comment: If I understood what you are asking correctly, for that record, if I retrieve the value from the dictionary for the key "elevationKey", it returns (AnyObject?)nil

Comment: Yes, that's probably the problem and also the reason it assigns a String. I would suggest postprocessing it somehow - make sure it's the right type, the parser can do wild things with it.

Comment: Thanks Michal. The post processing described below to include null worked to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The screenshot from the debugger shows that `elevationFt` is an empty string, which is not a number or null, so it is not a valid value for an optional int property.

Comment: Looking at the JSON string I posted, how would you represent the an integer value that was not present? I have always seen it as an empty string, so I am not sure what to change here. In addition, all the other optional properties that are strings on the Airport class have their values to null after the create function returns.

Comment: JSON has `null` specifically to represent a value that is not present.

Comment: Thanks. I got used to seeing things one way and didn't look any further in the JSON. That worked. Don't know if you want to write something more formal up, but replacing each of the empty strings with null in the parsing routine allows me to now use the optional int type in my model. Thanks!